# Lista por jquery e ação submit

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tenho este script, que ao selecionar um estado, ele carrega os municípios que estão funcionando, mas se eu tento salvar por uma ação **submit** ele mostra o erro. Mas o que o usuário escolheu no município some, e os municípios ficam em branco.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#estadoMunicipio')
    .change(
      function() {
        if ($(this).val()) {
          $('#municipioEstado').hide();
          $('.carregando').show();
          $.getJSON('/nota-fiscal-servico-web/buscaMunicipioPorPaisEstado/' + $(this).val(),
            function(j) {
              var options = '<option value="" class="chosen-select">'
              +'</option>';
              for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                options += '<option class="chosen-select" value="' +
                j[i].id + '">'
                + j[i].descricao
                + '</option>';
              }
              $('#municipioEstado')
              .html(options)
              .show();
              $('.carregando').hide();
            });
        } else {
          $('#municipioEstado')
          .html(
            '<option  class="chosen-select" value="">-- Escolha um estado --</option>');
        }
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Podes postar uma simulação em um JSFIDDLE ou PLUNKER?

Comment: Você recarrega a Página quando mostra os erros certo?

Answer (score 0):

É porque quando você recarrega a Página, você precisa dar `trigger` no campo, para ele refazer a lógica que está no seu evento de `change`. Tente colocar isso no seu Script:

```
$(function(){
    $('#estadoMunicipio').trigger('change');
})
```